# How to get network signal strength using WifiManager in below Android 11?

Tags: android, wifimanager, signal-strength

Deprecated solution is `WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi, 5)`

As per [Official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#calculateSignalLevel(int,%20int)) new solution is `wifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi)` and this is applicable for SDK 30 (Android 11) and above.

How to calculate the signal level below SDK 30 devices?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.